# Jquery BlockUI Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, blockui

I want to block an IFRAME element using the BlockUI jQuery plugin.

Please give me an example how to do that.

Comment: Clock an iframe?? please improve your question, I don't get it...

Comment: @user587159 - You need to post your code in your question that you are having problems with. It's impossible to do help you without that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered looking at the BlockUI docs?

I think http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element is exactly what you want.
I'm not completely sure if that works in case the iframe loaded an external site though as it seems to modify the element's DOM and not just create an overlay outside of the element.

Comment: thank for your reply,I am  trying the exactly same with loading external site, with iframe, it is not working for can you please suggest any alternative to do it

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your after. As ThiefMaster explained, you need to wrap an external DIV element around the iframe.

```
<div id="iframeContainer" style="width:800;height:600px;">
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#iframeContainer').block({ message: null });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

include script jquery.min.js before jquery.block.js, 
working example:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>BlockUISample</title>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                $('#iframeContainer').block({ message: null });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="block"></input>
        <div id="iframeContainer" style="width: 800; height: 600px;">
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```